# Whether should IDBObjectStore.transaction.oncomplete be necessarily used after the IDBDatabase.createObjectStore?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I was reading this article from MDN: [Using IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB).

There are 2 examples which both create a new object store and add data after creation.

The first example use `IDBObjectStore.transaction.oncomplete` to make sure the store creation is finished before adding data.

```
var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("customers", { keyPath: "ssn" });
// Use transaction oncomplete to make sure the objectStore creation is 
// finished before adding data into it.
objectStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
  var customerObjectStore = db.transaction("customers", "readwrite").objectStore("customers");
  customerData.forEach(function(customer) {
    customerObjectStore.add(customer);
  });
};
```

However, when I looked at the following example, it made me a little confused:

```
var objStore = db.createObjectStore("names", { autoIncrement : true });
customerData.forEach(function(customer) {
  objStore.add(customer.name);
});
```

As you can see the data is added without a transaction, thus, in theory, the second example would cause some problem while trying to add data before object store is ready.

Surprisingly, both of 2 examples works

I wonder which one should be preferred and why it is preferred. Is using a transaction really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Use the second example, the first is not needed.

Comment: I am afraid you did not answer the question.